# ng generate module heroes/heroes --module app --flat --routing in this ng command what --flat mean

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am learning Angular routing going through Angular doc but not able to understand the `--flat` in `ng` command

```
ng generate module heroes/heroes --module app --flat --routing
```

Comment: Did you read https://angular.io/cli/generate#module?

Answer (score 7):

```
ng generate module app-routing --flat --module=app
```

> --flat puts the file in src/app instead of its own folder.
>
> --module=app tells the CLI to register it in the imports array of the AppModule.

Read more here https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

Answer (score 4):

This is what the Angular Docs have to say:

> When true, creates the new files at the top level of the current project root.
>
> Default: false

Since you've written `heroes/heroes`, the files will be created in a folder named `heroes`

Read more about it [**here**](https://angular.io/cli/generate#module)